# How to use an ios app to upload a image to Node.JS server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js

everyone, I'm trying to upload a image from my ios device to a web server which is written in Node.JS.

I use formidable in the web server and it works well when I upload a file via browser, however, I can't figure out how to upload a file from an IOS app. It seems that the request sent by IOS app can't be parsed by formidable..

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611287/uploading-image-to-server-via-node-js-from-an-ios-app)(I followed this post to write the POST request in IOS app) shows the ios app client code I wonder what does the server side look like..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have provided enough information to receive an adequate answer. However, if you can post fine using a browser but not with iOS, to me that seems like either a header issue in the POST request, or iOS is not issuing a POST request. You will have to debug those points to see where the problem may be.

Are you getting any. errors in node when posting from iOS? That will reveal a lot of information.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I figured out the problem, it was because of the request body, I didn't add boundary properly..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out how to do this...in short, I wasn't building the request body in proper format.. I messed up with 'boundary'. My server side code actually works well after I changed my IOS app code, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611287/uploading-image-to-server-via-node-js-from-an-ios-app) is giving the correct way to write IOS client code.
I will post my server code here in case someone may need it.

```
    app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    //console.log(form);
    //console.log(req._readableState);
    //console.log(req.body);    
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.end('success'); 
    });
    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
         var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
         //console.log(temp_path);      
         var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;       
         var new_location = path.dirname(require.main.filename) + "/uploads/fullsize/";
         fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
            if (err) {
                 console.error(err);
            } else {
                   console.log("success!")
            }
        });
    });
});
```